# Malformed Packet: Django admin nested form can't submit, connection was reset

Tags: python, django, django-admin, nested-forms

I have a django nested admin form and below code is my `admin.py` file content:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from django.db.models import Q
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX, identify_hasher
from django.forms.utils import flatatt
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _, ugettext
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from nested_admin.nested import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin

from HomeMakers.apps.system.models import Dependant, Benefit, User, \
    Unit, Stack, Parking
from mtools.fields import UniqueValueWidget, PersianDateField


class DependantAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Dependant
    birth_date = PersianDateField(label=u'تاریخ تولد')


class DependantAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Dependant
    form = DependantAdminForm

    extra = 0
    exclude = ['changed_status', 'new_obj']
    can_delete = True


class BenefitSubAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Benefit
    extra = 1
    min_num = 0

    exclude = ['changed_status', 'new_obj']
    can_delete = True


class NewUserAdminForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    username = forms.RegexField(label=u"کد ملی", max_length=30, regex=r'^\d{8,10}$',
                                widget=UniqueValueWidget,
                                error_messages={'invalid': u"مقدار وارد شده قابل قبول نمیباشد."})
    birth_date = PersianDateField(from_year=1290, to_year=1400, label=_('Birth Date'))
    start_date = PersianDateField(from_year=1290, to_year=1400, label=u"تاریخ شروع به کار")

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
        return username


class ReadOnlyPasswordHashWidget(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs):
        encoded = value
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)

        if not encoded or encoded.startswith(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX):
            summary = mark_safe(u"<strong>%s</strong>" % _("No password set."))
        else:
            try:
                hasher = identify_hasher(encoded)
            except ValueError:
                summary = mark_safe(u"<strong>%s</strong>" % _(
                    "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."))
            else:
                summary = u'''format_html_join('',
                                           "<strong>{0}</strong>: {1} ",
                                           ((ugettext(key), value)
                                            for key, value in hasher.safe_summary(encoded).items())
                                           )'''

        return format_html(u"<div{0}>{1}</div>", flatatt(final_attrs), summary)


class ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(forms.Field):
    widget = ReadOnlyPasswordHashWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("required", False)
        super(ReadOnlyPasswordHashField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def bound_data(self, data, initial):
        # Always return initial because the widget doesn't
        # render an input field.
        return initial

    def _has_changed(self, initial, data):
        return False


class EditUserAdminForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User

    birth_date = PersianDateField(from_year=1290, to_year=1400, label=_('Birth Date'))
    start_date = PersianDateField(from_year=1290, to_year=1400, label=u"تاریخ شروع به کار")
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))

    error_messages = {'duplicate_username': 'An user by this international code already exists.'}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditUserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'] = forms.RegexField(label=u"کد ملی", max_length=30, regex=r'^\d{8,10}$',
                                                   widget=UniqueValueWidget(),
                                                   error_messages={'invalid': u"مقدار وارد شده قابل قبول نمیباشد."})
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['value'] = self.instance.username

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if username != self.instance.username and User.objects.filter(username=username).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
        return username


class UnitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Unit
    installment_begin_date = PersianDateField(label=u'تاریخ شروع اقساط')


class StackSubAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Stack
    extra = 1


class ParkingSubAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Parking
    extra = 1


class UnitSubAdmin(NestedStackedInline):  #(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Unit
    form = UnitForm
    extra = 0

    inlines = [ParkingSubAdmin, StackSubAdmin]
    exclude = ['sum_of_pays', 'parkings', 'warehouse']


class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin, NestedModelAdmin):
    model = User
    ordering = ['last_name']
    list_per_page = 10
    add_form = NewUserAdminForm
    form = EditUserAdminForm
    list_display = ['user_thumb', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    list_filter = ['units__project', 'groups']

    formfield_overrides = {
        # models.DateField: {'widget': PersianDateWidget}
    }

    '''fields = (
        'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
        'gender', 'birth_date', 'picture', 'certificate_no', 'birth_place', 'address', 'home_phone', 'work_phone',
        'mobile', 'personnel_code', 'international_code', 'job_field', 'self_employed_job_name', 'employment_type',
        'start_date', 'is_retired'
    )'''

    inlines = [DependantAdmin, UnitSubAdmin]  # & BenefitSubAdmin

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        key_fields = {'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')}
        if obj is not None:
            key_fields = {'fields': ('username', 'password')}

        fieldsets = (
            (None, key_fields),
            (u'اطلاعات تکمیلی', {'fields': (
                'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                'gender', 'birth_date', 'academic_degree', 'picture', 'international_card_scaned_file',
                'certificate_scaned_file_page1', 'certificate_scaned_file_page2', 'academic_degree_scaned_file',
                'job_edict_document', 'certificate_no', 'birth_place', 'address', 'home_phone', 'work_phone',
                'mobile', 'personnel_code', 'job_field', 'self_employed_job_name', 'employment_type', 'start_date',
                'is_retired'
                )}
             ),
            (u'سطوح دسترسی', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'groups')})
            # , 'user_permissions', 'is_superuser')}),
            #  (u'تاریخ های مهم', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})
        )
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets = (
                (None, key_fields),
                (u'اطلاعات تکمیلی', {'fields': (
                    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                    'gender', 'birth_date', 'academic_degree', 'picture', 'international_card_scaned_file',
                    'certificate_scaned_file_page1', 'certificate_scaned_file_page2', 'academic_degree_scaned_file',
                    'job_edict_document', 'certificate_no', 'birth_place', 'address', 'home_phone', 'work_phone',
                    'mobile', 'personnel_code', 'job_field', 'self_employed_job_name', 'employment_type', 'start_date',
                    'is_retired'
                    )}
                 ),
                (u'سطوح دسترسی', {'fields': (
                         'is_active',
                         'is_staff',
                         'is_superuser',
                         'user_permissions',
                         'groups'
                    )
                })
                #  (u'تاریخ های مهم', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})
            )
        return fieldsets

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return User.objects.all()
        return User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Group
    filter_horizontal = ('permissions',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "permissions" and not request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs["queryset"] = Permission.objects.exclude(
                Q(codename__startswith='add_') |
                Q(codename__startswith='change_') |
                Q(codename__startswith='delete_')
            )
        return super(GroupAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field,
            request,
            **kwargs
        )

    def save_model(self, request, group, form, change):
        perms = []
        for p in group.permissions.all():
            if p.codename.startswith('add_') or \
                 p.codename.startswith('change_') or \
                 p.codename.startswith('delete_'):
                perms.append(p)
        super(GroupAdmin, self).save_model(request, group, form, change)
        form.cleaned_data['permissions'] = list(
            form.cleaned_data['permissions']
        )
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            form.cleaned_data['permissions'].extend(perms)
        form.cleaned_data['permissions'] = list(set(
            form.cleaned_data['permissions']))
        group.save()


# register new user admin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

When i developing and run devserver on localhost anything work nice, but on the server and by domain i can't submit this form by **The connection was reset** message.
Below code is my apache2 configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress"

#    ServerName localhost

#    Alias /wordpress /var/www/wordpress
#    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
#        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#        AllowOverride None
#        Order Deny,Allow
#        Allow from all
#    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /m3s /var/www/m3s/HomeMakers/wsgi.py
    #ProxyPass        /m3s/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    #ProxyPassReverse /m3s/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    #<Proxy http://127.0.0.1:8000/m3s/>
    #    Order Allow,Deny
    #    Allow from all
    #</Proxy>


    # WSGIDaemonProcess sentry python-path=/var/www/sentry/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    # WSGIScriptAlias /exceptions/tracker /var/www/sentry/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/wsgi.py

    Alias /ufiles  /var/www/m3s/media_files
    Alias /static /var/www/m3s/sfiles
    Alias /_static /var/www/sentry/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/static
    Alias /mydb/admin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    <Directory "/var/www/m3s/HomeMakers/">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/m3s/sfiles/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i tried to using **uwsgi** and **mod_proxy** together but my problem not resolved. After i monitor **access.log** and my server port 80 by **tshark**, tshard shows me this request but in **access.log** file i can't see any change...

Apache logs in info mode:

```
[Sun Jan 29 21:15:47.896062 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7596] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Sun Jan 29 21:15:47.896100 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7596] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.11+.
[Sun Jan 29 21:15:47.898887 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7596] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.11+ configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 29 21:15:47.898913 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7596] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 29 21:16:43.833245 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 7599] [client 84.241.62.118:44316] mod_wsgi (pid=7599, process='', application='ut3taavoni.ir|/m3s'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/m3s/HomeMakers/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Jan 29 21:16:45.317557 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7599] DEBUG 2017-01-29 21:16:45,317 base 7599 -1220638144 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteConfig object at 0xada5a12c>
[Sun Jan 29 21:16:47.484799 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 7602] [client 84.241.62.118:42751] mod_wsgi (pid=7602, process='', application='ut3taavoni.ir|/m3s'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/m3s/HomeMakers/wsgi.py'., referer: http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/?_changelist_filters=q%3D0065231619
[Sun Jan 29 21:16:48.899865 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7602] DEBUG 2017-01-29 21:16:48,899 base 7602 -1220638144 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteConfig object at 0xada5a12c>
[Sun Jan 29 21:17:33.961983 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 7603] [client 84.241.62.118:20515] mod_wsgi (pid=7603, process='', application='ut3taavoni.ir|/m3s'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/m3s/HomeMakers/wsgi.py'., referer: http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/?_changelist_filters=q%3D0065231619
[Sun Jan 29 21:17:35.360116 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7603] DEBUG 2017-01-29 21:17:35,360 base 7603 -1220638144 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteConfig object at 0xada5a1ac>
```

And my access.log file content:

```
192.0.102.40 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:37:30 +0330] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 372 "-" "jetmon/1.0 (Jetpack Site Uptime Monitor by WordPress.com)"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:37:56 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4627 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:37:57 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10588 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:38:51 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/?q=0065231619 HTTP/1.1" 200 4195 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:38:51 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10588 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/?q=0065231619" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:38:54 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/?_changelist_filters=q%3D0065231619 HTTP/1.1" 200 14967 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/?q=0065231619" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:38:55 +0330] "GET /m3s/m3s-panel/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10588 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/?_changelist_filters=q%3D0065231619" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xxx.241.62.118 - - [29/Jan/2017:22:38:55 +0330] "GET /m3s/_nested_admin/server-data.js HTTP/1.1" 200 388 "http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/?_changelist_filters=q%3D0065231619" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
```

My related question on ServerFault site:
https://serverfault.com/questions/827813/apache-respons-to-get-but-not-to-post

**Update:**
I ran *tshark* again and saw below *important* line:

```
7 0.754812317  5.113.18.90 -> xxx.156.28.145 HTTP 1434 POST /m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/ HTTP/1.1 [Malformed Packet]
```

Below is my browser "Request Payload":

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Length: 4614

-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

STMAQ1bSTuWsl9CelQBK5S2QjUKIfZ1Z
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

9265291619
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"

اعظم
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

جعفری
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

jafariphd@ut.ac.ir
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"

0
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_0"

15
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_1"

6
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_2"

1356
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degree"

5
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="international_card_scaned_file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degree_scaned_file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job_edict_document"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_no"

11909
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_place"

تهران
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"

تهران -میدان پاستور-خ پاستور غربی-خ آژیده-کوچه آفین-پ 7-طبقه اول غربی
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="home_phone"

66915902
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="work_phone"

66409696
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile"

09125114282
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="personnel_code"

26687
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job_field"

1
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="self_employed_job_name"

کارشناس معماری
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="employment_type"

3
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_date_0"

1
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_date_1"

1
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="start_date_2"

1385
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="is_active"

on
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="is_staff"

on
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="groups"

3
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_continue"

ذخیره و ادامهٔ ویرایش
-----------------------------51995842320268179811054389612--
```

But now my questions is how this problem happend and how can i resolve this?

Comment: What is in Apache error log for your virtual host and main error log?

Comment: No changed anything in **errors.log** and **access.log** files, thanks @danshi.

Comment: Try to put "LogLevel info" in httpd.conf. Also check this out http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html.

Comment: I updated my question, @danshi you can show my logging settings now.

Comment: I mean you should increase logging level of the Apache, put "LogLevel info" in httpd.conf and restart httpd.

Comment: @danshi i updated my question again, thanks.

Comment: I've followed your links and can reproduce your issue on login form. If you don't see any errors in your virtual host error log and main error log, then try to update your apache, or rebuild/reinstall it, update your OS. I can't tell more without direct access to your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allowed my friend accessing to my VPS, then he said me that my problem related to wordpress and showed me below log after page loads and submit pressed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/javascript

GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 6.0.1; Mobile; rv:51.0.3) Gecko/51.0.3 Firefox/51.0.3
Host: ut3taavoni.ir
Accept-Encoding: gzip
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:39 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
Host: ut3taavoni.ir
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 6.0.1; Mobile; rv:51.0) Gecko/51.0 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/
Cookie: csrftoken=3yVd9UL6g69U6Chhy5MQqIcPAy9VyGUM; sessionid=d8xvyszgs05occnnac57lz0vd8zuvqy5
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------6169424391163634213177052432
Content-Length: 19033
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_0"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_1"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_2"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degree"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="international_card_scaned_file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degr
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

POST /m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ut3taavoni.ir
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 6.0.1; Mobile; rv:51.0) Gecko/51.0 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://ut3taavoni.ir/m3s/m3s-panel/members/user/501/
Cookie: csrftoken=3yVd9UL6g69U6Chhy5MQqIcPAy9VyGUM; sessionid=d8xvyszgs05occnnac57lz0vd8zuvqy5
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------6169424391163634213177052432
Content-Length: 19033
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_0"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_1"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date_2"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degree"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="international_card_scaned_file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="certificate_scaned_file_page2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="academic_degr
Host: ut3taavoni.ir
User-Agent: jetmon/1.0 (Jetpack Site Uptime Monitor by WordPress.com)
Connection: close

POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1487776996.4416921138763427734375 HTTP/1.1
Host: ut3taavoni.ir
User-Agent: WordPress/4.7.2; http://ut3taavoni.ir
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Referer: http://ut3taavoni.ir/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1487776996.4416921138763427734375
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:23:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: wfvt_2147194919=58adace494d41; expires=Wed, 22-Feb-2017 15:53:16 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:23:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: wfvt_2147194919=58adace4a1507; expires=Wed, 22-Feb-2017 15:53:16 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
Link: <http://ut3taavoni.ir/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <wp.me/P8gOjR-2>; rel=shortlink
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:24:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: wfvt_2147194919=58adad47d7d5c; expires=Wed, 22-Feb-2017 15:54:55 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow
Link: <http://ut3taavoni.ir/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:24:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: wfvt_2147194919=58adad47e1c49; expires=Wed, 22-Feb-2017 15:54:55 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow
Link: <http://ut3taavoni.ir/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 15:20:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Thanks my dear friend Amir

Answer (score 2):

We have the same issue on freshly installed system with Apache 2.4 on Cent OS 64 bits. Apache drops connections some time, it was behind nginx, so we get 502 Gateway error very often. There were nothing in logs, nothing with enabled debug, no crash dumps and so on.

The only solution that fixes the problem - rebuild/reinstall Apache completely. We've found this solution when added debug output code to Apache sources and rebuild, wondering how our debug code fixes the problem. But it was just re-build.

P.S. Also carefully follow this recommendations on debug WSGI http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html